Android version of .NET MAUI not displaying data
The Android version of the datagrid of .NET MAUI is not displaying any data, based off of testing the most recent version, unaltered, both on an Android devices as well as an Android emulator. It should be noted that the Windows version does display the data correctly in the grid.Android Version Windows VErsion. Is it a platform specific issue of the .NET MAUI datagrid?
This is my XAML code for the datagrid. Since it is a mobile application. The datagrid should be able to be scrolled sideways to make up for the limited space in a mobile device.
<ScrollView Orientation="Both" Grid.Row="1">
    <dg:DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"
             ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCount}"
             SelectionEnabled="True"
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItems}"
             RowHeight="30"
             HeaderHeight="30"
             HeaderBackground="SkyBlue"
             ActiveRowColor="LightGray"
             BorderColor="White"
             BorderThickness="0.5">
        <dg:DataGrid.Columns>
            <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Counter" PropertyName="ItemCounter" Width="80*"/>
            <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Item Code" PropertyName="ItemCode" Width="100*"/>
            <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Description" PropertyName="ItemDescription" Width="200*"/>
            <dg:DataGridColumn Title="UOM" PropertyName="ItemUom" Width="80*"/>
            <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Batch &amp; Lot No." PropertyName="ItemBatchLotNumber" Width="120*"/>
            <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Expiry" PropertyName="ItemExpiry" Width="100*"/>
            <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Quantity" PropertyName="ItemQuantity" Width="80*"/>
        </dg:DataGrid.Columns>
    </dg:DataGrid>
</ScrollView>


This is an issue of the third party NuGet package. You can report it as an issue on the GitHub or you can try to update the package to the latest version.

I am using this plugin in one of my projects and it works just fine can you create a GitHub sample and reproduce this issue
